# How to filter rows containing a string in several columns

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe and I need to find rows that start with letter 'd' in all columns[1:]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['vamjy', 'tjny', 'xrvwb', 'kuqjlat', 'muagny', 'cuw', 'ekw'],
      'text': ['dadcd', 'abecc', 'dddda', 'ddade', 'eaedd', 'caceb', 'edded'],
      'line': ['eebdd', 'abbcb', 'cbddd', 'dbeac', 'cabbd', 'acaca', 'ebace'],
      'note': ['bdded', 'bbebb', 'adcca', 'decee', 'dbcce', 'eabbc', 'aaacc']})
```

I could write

```
df[(df['text'].str[0]=='d') & (df['line'].str[0]=='d') & (df['note'].str[0]=='d')]
```

and it works but I need something more intelligent like this:

```
df[df[x].str[0] == 'd' for x in df.columns[1:]]
```

(because there are a lot of columns in my df) but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```py
cond = (
    df[["text", "line", "note"]]
    .apply(lambda col: col.str.startswith("d"))
    .all(axis=1)
)
df[cond]
```

Explanation:

- Get 3 columns from the data frame
- For each column, check if it starts with the letter "d"
- Check all 3 columns satisfy the condition

---

You can extend this concept to check that each column starts with a different string:

```py
# `text` must start with a, `line` with b, and `note` with c
lookup = {
    "text": "a",
    "line": "b",
    "note": "c",
}
cond = (
    df[["text", "line", "note"]]
    .apply(lambda col: col.str.startswith(lookup[col.name]))
    .all(axis=1)
)
```

Or with continuous columns:

```py
cond = (
   df.iloc[:, 1:]
   .apply(...)
   .all(axis=1)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Still I have too many columns and I would like to get short note for them.
cond = (
    df[[df.columns[1:]]]
    .apply(lambda col: col.str.startswith("d"))
    .all(axis=1))
does not work without columns names

Comment: Nice idea to show the generalization to different starting characters ;)

Comment: @Tatiana you can use the `df.loc[:, 1:]` syntax. For lots of columns, I prefer declaring them all in a list `cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]`, then `df[cols].apply(....)`. Referring to columns by their ordinal positions make them a bit obscure and prone to problems with the data source change their positions.

Comment: Finally it works like this:
df[df[df.columns[1:]].applymap(lambda x: x.startswith('d')).all(axis=1)]
my version is old, new one can work with map instead of applymap.
Thank you for your help!